# Display the JSON information into a drop down.Angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

This is my JSON data:

```
{
    result: 1,
    vote_time_slots: {
    2016-08-07: {
        diff: 1080,
        slots: {
            08:42: false, 09:36: false, 06:54: false, 04:30: false,
            09:18: false, 09:00: false, 08:24: false, 05:42: false,
            06:00: false, 10:12: false, 08:06: false, 06:36: false,
            07:12: false, 07:48: false, 05:24: false, 06:18: false,
            09:54: false, 07:30: false, 10:30: false, 05:06: false,
            04:48: false
        }
    },
    2016-07-25: {
        diff: 1080,
        slots: {
            08:42: false,
            09:36: false,
            06:54: false,
        }
    },
```

I want the time slots like 08:42, 09:36 and so on to be getting into a drop down.

**please tell me how to navigate to slots field and get only slot values Filtered on false (which is value)**

```
<li ng-repeat="c in eventTimings | filter: ????:false"><a>{{(c)}}
```

how to show  based on filter also?

If i have true value the respective time slot should not show in drop down.

Comment: Please give more information about your json data. What do you mean by navigating ?

Comment: navigating means i need to go to the slots object to get the information from it  First from vote_time_slots-->2016-08-07-->slot--->get necessary info

Comment: You can use "." to access object properties or you can "navigate" by accessing the properties just like accessing array elements. For your case, vote_time_slots.2016-08-07.slots

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
slots = {
            "08:42": false, "09:36": false, "06:54": false, "04:30": false,
            "09:18": false, "09:00": false, "08:24": false, "05:42": false,
            "06:00": false, "10:12": false, "08:06": false, "06:36": false,
            "07:12": false, "07:48": false, "05:24": false, "06:18": false,
            "09:54": false, "07:30": false, "10:30": false, "05:06": false,
            "04:48": false
        };
var arr = [];
for(var prop in slots) { arr.push(prop); }
console.log(arr);
```

From here on you repeat on the arr

```
ng-repeat="opt in arr" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to iterate over the properties of slots (since it is in object format). Please do search in stackoverflow before asking a question.

See if the answer in following link helps and write a custom filter using the logic:

[Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Comment: please tell me how to navigate to slots in my JSON to get information from it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple [solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/K3520AyjSUVCqW5JOOBh?p=preview):

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.slots" ng-if='!value'>{{key}}</li>
```

Another approach - to create [custom filter](https://plnkr.co/edit/yuVqjOrmH1AUxbaRx1iw?p=preview):

**HTML:**

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.slots | custom : false">{{key}}</li>
```

**Javascript:**

```
.filter('custom', function() {
  return function(input, search) {
    var result = {};
    angular.forEach(input, function(value, key) {
      if (value == search) {
        result[key] = value;
      }
    });
    return result;
}});
```

Comment: please tell me how to navigate to  slots in my JSON to get information from it

Comment: This answer gives you a complete picture of what to do. I don't get your question, what do you mean by "navigate to slots"?

Comment: @user1851003: For example: `var data = yourJson['2016-08-07'];`